# how to divide integer and take some part

Tags: python

I have a variable holding x length number, in real time I do not know x. I just want to get divide this value into two. For example;

```
   variable holds a =  01029108219821082904444333322221111
   I just want to take last 16 integers as a new number, like
              b = 0  # initialization
              b = doSomeOp (a)
              b = 4444333322221111 # new value of b
```

How can I divide the integer ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
>>> a = 1029108219821082904444333322221111
>>> a % 10**16
4444333322221111
```

or, using string manipulation:

```
>>> int(str(a)[-16:])
4444333322221111
```

If you don't know the "length" of the number in advance, you can calculate it:

```
>>> import math
>>> a % 10 ** int(math.log10(a)/2)
4444333322221111
>>> int(str(a)[-int(math.log10(a)/2):])
4444333322221111
```

And, of course, for the "other half" of the number, it's

```
>>> a // 10 ** int(math.log10(a)/2)   # Use a single / with Python 2
102910821982108290
```

**EDIT:**

If your actual question is "How can I divide a *string* in half", then it's

```
>>> a = "\x00*\x10\x01\x00\x13\xa2\x00@J\xfd\x15\xff\xfe\x00\x000013A200402D5DF9"
>>> half = len(a)//2
>>> front, back = a[:half], a[half:]
>>> front
'\x00*\x10\x01\x00\x13¢\x00@Jý\x15ÿþ\x00\x00'
>>> back
'0013A200402D5DF9'
```

Comment: I have tried int(str(a){-16:]), error emitted `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10:`

Comment: I get a `SyntaxError` here because of the curly brace. Are you sure you copied that correctly?

Comment: I tested his question with ~30 numbers in the string and failed to notice that i was actually taking from number 16.

Comment: what is the meaning of `TypeError: a float is required`?

Comment: @user2386107: You provided a non-numeric parameter to a function that expects a number.

Comment: @TimPietzcker I have this riduculus number `~\x00*\x10\x01\x00\x13\xa2\x00@J\xfd\x15\xff\xfe\x00\x000013A200402D5DF9` stored in **string**. The meaningful part is last 16 `0013A200402D5DF9`. I want to extract this number.

Comment: @user2386107: Why did you ask "how to divide an integer" then? Why make it pointless for us to answer a question that has next to nothing to do with your actual problem?

Answer (score 0):

I would just explot slices here by casting it to a string, taking a slice and convert it back to a number.

```
b = int(str(a)[-16:])
```

Comment: That gives you `904444333322221111`.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is:

```
b = int(str(a)[len(str(a))/2:])
```